# How to change the Midpoint circle algorithm in order to take a Starting angle and ending Angle?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, bresenham

I've looked many places and haven't found any resources (that I understand) that explain how to turn the standard Midpoint circle algorithm (which uses octants to create the whole circle)  into only considering a specific 'slice' of the circle. I'm using this to find the tiles within a line of sight radius.

the code I'm using is the basic Wikipedia code of how to implement the algorithm.

I'm using java inside "Processing" to prototype things out.

I'm trying to understand how this algorithm works so I can modify it, but I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The midpoint algorithm or Bresenham algorithm can be extended with a condition if the point you are rasterizing falls into the range you have specified by the angles (points). To get the range you would have to find the starting and ending point on the circle. This can be easily accomplished with help of polar coordinates. If we have a circle with radius `r`, angle `theta` and center `C(x0,y0)` the point on the circle can be computed as `pCircle(x,y) = (x0 + r  * cos theta, y0 + r * sin theta)`. Note that the angle is in radians.

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with trigonometry and polar coordinate system. After researching further I found something that demonstrates what you described. 
For those who ran into the same problem here is a link that puts it to practice. 
 
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/769733.html                  

thank you Croolman!